# iOS startMonitoringForRegion, didExitRegion, didEnterRegion, didStartMonitoringForRegion. Methods not firing properly

Tags: ios, location, region, geofencing

I run my code in the iPhone simulator, and from the simulator menu, I choose:
"Debug, Location, Apple" to set my current location at Apple's Cupertino location.

Then I choose from the simulator menu:  "Debug, Location, Freeway Drive".  The current location properly updates along the 280 freeway.

My code should create a "geo-fence" of 1500 meters.  Every time the device reaches the boundary - it drops a pin and draws a circle.

Problems.....

1. "didExitRegion" is not being called at the proper distance, it's being called several miles down the freeway.
2. "didStartMonitoringForRegion" is never called.

Any help is appreciated!!  Thanks!!

Here is my code:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MKMapView.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>

@property(nonatomic,strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property(nonatomic,strong) MKMapView *myMapView;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "POI.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize locationManager;
@synthesize myMapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];

    if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    myMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [myMapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [myMapView setDelegate:self];
    [myMapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:myMapView];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{return NO;}

#pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate methods

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error
{    NSLog(@"%@: %@", @"monitoring failed", error.description); }

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{    NSLog(@"%@", @"monitoring succeeded"); }

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{    NSLog(@"%@: %@", @"region entered", region.identifier);}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"%@: %@", @"region exited", region.identifier);

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    if(status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"%@", @"New Location");

    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    NSInteger radius = 1500;

    CLRegion *reg = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:newLocation.coordinate radius:radius identifier:@"userLocation"];
    [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:reg desiredAccuracy:25];

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    POI *poi = [[POI alloc] init];
    [poi setCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];
    [poi setTitle:[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    [myMapView addAnnotation:poi];

    MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate radius:radius];
    [myMapView addOverlay:circle];
}

// Called when there is an error getting the location
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{    NSLog(@"%@: %@", @"get location failed", error.description);   }

#pragma mark MKMapViewDelegate methods

-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKCircleView *circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle:overlay];

    circleView.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    circleView.alpha = 0.25;

    return circleView;
}

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    static NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"annotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

    if(newAnnotation == nil)
        newAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

    [newAnnotation setAnimatesDrop:YES];
    [newAnnotation setCanShowCallout:YES];

    return newAnnotation;
}

@end
```

POI.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface POI : MKPointAnnotation
{
    NSString *subtitle;
    NSString *title;
    NSInteger tag;
    MKPinAnnotationColor pinColor;
}

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *subtitle;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *title;
@property(nonatomic,assign) NSInteger tag;
@property(nonatomic,assign) MKPinAnnotationColor pinColor;

@end
```

POI.m

```
#import "POI.h"
@implementation POI
@synthesize tag, title, subtitle, pinColor;
@end
```

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. Did you figure out the problem?

Comment: No, I think it's simply not very accurate.  :(